# Trying to publish my app in vs using a ftp and clickonce, but can't seem to connect to host website with the following error

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, ftp, clickonce

So I'm following this youtube video:

https://youtu.be/SvZCFtaJcsk

When I click publish now I get the following error:

Failed to connect to 'ftp://dotnetgate.com/' with the following error: Unable to create the Web site 'ftp://dotnetgate.com'.  Can't connect to 'dotnetgate.com'. Check the server name and proxy settings. If the settings are correct, the server may be temporarily unavailable.

What's causing this and how do I fix it, I already created an account and put in the username and password for the windows form deployment. Can I actually even publish anything to that website because the guy in the video does, but then I read somewhere you can't actually do it on that site. Can I literally publish to any site I own and have an account on? So something like a bluehost server for example if I wanted too?

Comment: FTP isn't a web site, it's a completely different protocol. Does that FTP server even exist? Is it running? You can't publish something to a non-existent FTP server. `dotnetgate.com` is a web site. Even if it runs an FTP server it will only be for administrators to publish new code, and probably *won't* run on the same URL

Answer (score 0):

Based on my test, I reproduced your problem. And according to my further research, I find that we need to create a ftp site before we publish it.

You can follow the following link to create the ftp site.

[Creating a New FTP Site Using IIS Manager](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/publish/using-the-ftp-service/creating-a-new-ftp-site-in-iis-7#creating-a-new-ftp-site-using-iis-manager)

After creating the ftp site, you can paste the correspond url to the publish folder location:

[image]

Finally, if you used the specific user in the ftp site, please use the same username and password in the publish setting.

[image]

[image]